# Macro to zip certain files with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula, zip

Every week I have to run this cycle count report. When the report is finished, I have to manually take about 30 files and group them by location and zip the files. I'm new with VBA and I'm trying to create a macro that will automatically group a certain set of files and zip them together. Also I need to be able to add or remove any files that are grouped together. Below is a list of the files and how I need them grouped and where I'm trying to save them to. Below is some code that I have for it. I know it's missing some things.

Here are two files that I'm talking about. If someone can show me what to put in the macro to make this work and to group other files into other zip folders that would be great.

Zip folder named `CYC 06-06-11-18` includes these files. `C06-06-11-18, C6K-06-11-18, C6M-06-11-18, C6V-06-11-18, CQU-06-11-18, CSU-06-11-18, T06-06-11-18,T6C-06-11-18, TSU-06-11-18.`

Zip folder named `CYC D1-06-11-18` includes these files. `CD1-06-11-18, CS1-06-11-18, TD1-06-11-18, TS1-06-11-18.`

The files are all in one folder and the zip folder can either be in the same folder or a new one. As long as the zip file can by named "CYC 06" or "CYC 11", or "CYC T1". I don't have to include the date on the zip folder.

These files and the zip folders are being saved in the file path below. Which is what I would like to use if possible.

```
S:\ACCT\Inventory Control & Product Costing\Inventory Control - Reporting\RM Cycle Count - Data Collection\Zip Files
```

Here is the macro I've been working with.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim fs o As Object
Dim result As Boolean

Sub Folder Info()
Application. Screen  Updating   = False
'------------------------------------
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim s t r Path As String
    s t r  Path = 
    x = 0
    Set fs o = Create Object    ("Scripting. File System Object")
'------------------------------------
'CHECK FOLDERS AND SUBFOLDERS
    result = Extract File Info    (s t r Path)
'------------------------------------
'CLEANUP
    Set fs o = Nothing
    Msg Box x & " files have been zipped."
Application. Screen Updating = True
End Sub


Private Function Extract File Info(fs pec)
    On Error Go To Err Handler
'------------------------------------
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim f l d r As Object, fi As Object, s f l d r As Object, o App As Object
    Dim Filename, f name As String
    Set f l d r = fs o. Get Folder(fs pec)
'------------------------------------
'CHECK FILES IN TOP FOLDER
    If f l d r. Files. Count <> 0 Then
        For Each fi In f l d r. Files
            s = Split(fi, ".")
            If In  St r (1, fi, "(C06)" “(CK6)” “(CB6)” “(C6M)” “(C6V)” “(CQU)” “(CSU)” “(T06)” “(T6C)” “(TQU)” “(TSU)”, 1) > 0 And U Case(Left(s(1), 2)) = "XL" Then
                s = Split(fi, ".")
                Filename = s(0) & ".zip"
                New Zip (CYC 06)
                f name = fi
                Set o App = Create Object("Shell. Application")
                o App. Name space(Filename).Copy Here s(0) & "." & s(1) 'F Name (I C t r)
                x = x + 1
            End If
access not allowed:
        Next
    End If
'------------------------------------
'CHECK SUBFOLDERS
    If f l d r. Sub Folders. Count > 0 Then
        For Each s f l d r In f l d r. Sub Folders
            Extract File Info (s f l d  r) 'RECURSIVE CHECK
        Next
    End If
'------------------------------------
'CLEANUP
permission denied:
    Extract File Info = True
    Set f l d r = Nothing
Exit Handler:
    Application. Screen Updating = True
    Exit Function
'------------------------------------
'HANDLE RETURNED ERROR
Err Handler:
    If Err.Number = 70 Then 'permission denied
        Err. Clear
        Msg Box f spec & Ch r (13) & "Permission Denied"
        Resume permission  denied
    Else
        Msg Box Err. Number & ": " & Err. Description
        Resume Exit Handler
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: not sure whether what you plan is feasable the way you tried. When having to work with ZIP files, I usually create a batch file as needed and let it control a tool like e.g. 7ZIP which then does the ZIP-job for you.

Comment: It may be easier and faster if you use vbscript and 7zip.